# How do I combine these three sentences?

Tags: sentence

How do I combine these three sentences:

> 1. I love that as a dentist, I can have the ability to take away pain from my patients with just one to two hours of operation.
> 2. I love that as a dentist, I can go on service trips often to communities that are in need of dental care.
> 3. I love that as a dentist, I can see the long term progress of my patients.

Is the way I did it below correct:

> I love that as a dentist, I can have the ability to take away pain from my patients with just one to two hours of operation, go on service trips often to communities that are in need of dental care, and see the long term progress of my patients.

Comment: Add a comma after "I love that".

Comment: Sorry, but requests for writing advice or editorial suggestions are not on-topic here, as there is no one right answer, and the question is unlikely to be helpful to future visitors. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how StackExchange can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The way you combined the sentences is not ideal.  A better way is:

I love that as a dentist I have the ability to take away pain from my patients with just one to two hours of operation, can go on service trips often to communities that are in need of dental care, and can see the long-term progress of my patients.

Or choose either "have the ability" or "can":

1) I love that as a dentist I can take away pain from my patients with just one to two hours of operation, go on service trips often to communities that are in need of dental care, and see the long term progress of my patients.

2) I love that as a dentist, I have the ability to take away pain from my patients with just one to two hours of operation, go on service trips often to communities that are in need of dental care, and see the long term progress of my patients.

Answer (score 0):

I would write:
I love that as a dentist I can take away my patients' pain with just one to two hours of operation, see the long-term progress of my patients, and go on service trips to communities that are in need of dental care.